# C++ struct in header file

Tags: c++

I'm not very familiar with structs.
But I created this:

in test.h:

```
class test {
public:
    struct Astruct
    {
        int age;
        int weight;
    };
    struct Astruct& MethodOne();
};
```

and in test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
test::test() {}
struct Astruct& test::MethodOne() {
    Astruct testStruct;
    // code to fill in testStruct
    return testStruct;
}
```

The goal of this code above is that I'm able to return a `struct` with `MethodOne`.

But on the line of

```
struct Astruct & test::MethodOne(){
```

it says :error: declaration is incompatible with what's in the header file.

I don't understand this. If I'd replace the struct with an `int` return type there wouldn't be an error?
What's wrong here?

And a second error I'm getting when I return testStruct: Error: a reference of type "Astruct&" (not const qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "test::Astruct"

Comment: Classic one: you return a reference to a temporary. Learn to compile your code with warning enabled and follow compiler instructions.

Comment: your usage of `struct` looks like you learned it from a C book. In C++ you only need to know that there is no difference between a `class` and a `struct`. And the second thing you need to know is that in a `class` the default access specifier is `private` while in a `struct` it is `public`, but thats really the only difference

Comment: `struct test::Astruct & test::MethodOne(){`, use class namespace. BTW the third error you'll have is "returning reference of temporary". Drop the reference in the return value.

Comment: Also, you name the temporary variable `testStuct` but you're returning `testStruct`.

Comment: Bogus code, missing semicolons (`;`)!!!

Comment: You don't need to use *nested* structures; they add more complexity to your project.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several errors (missing `;` etc.). A `class` is not different from a `struct` in C++. The only difference is the default access specifier which is `private` in a `class` and `public` in a `struct` (members and inheritance).

Structs are typically used to indicate that it actually is just a data structure with no logic or methods. Imho they are nice to encapsulate input and output of methods. If you want to have it for a member function it could look like this:

```
class Foo{
    public:
    struct BarIn {};              // need ; here
    struct BarOut {};             // and here
    BarOut bar(const BarIn& b){return BarOut();}
};


int main() {
    Foo::BarOut result = Foo().bar(Foo::BarIn());
}
```

Note that I had to write `Foo:BarOut` and `Foo::BarIn`, because the structs are declared inside the class. Also there is no need to write `struct` when you declare a variable of a type that is declared as `struct` (because there really is no difference between an instance of a `class` or `struct`).

Last but not least you should **never** return a reference (or pointer) to a local variable:

```
struct Astruct & test::MethodOne(){
    Astruct testStruct;
    return testStruct;            // testStruct is destroyed here
}                                 // and the returned ref is invalid
```